# Cannot launch PHPMyAdmin in EasyPHP DevServer 16.1.1

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I just downloaded EasyPHP DevServer 16.1.1, started it, started also :

- Apache 2.4.18 x86 - PHP 5.6.19 x86 Port: 80
- MySQL 5.7.11 x86 Port: 3306

and tried to launch PHPMyAdmin. I got the following answer :
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

Looking in the Apache log, I found the following warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Users\pascal\Documents\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5619vc11x86x160731134017\ext\php_mbstring.dll' - Le module sp\xef\xbf\xbdcifi\xef\xbf\xbd est introuvable.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Has anybody an idea ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting an answer, I tried to reinstall EasyPHP 16.1.1 and now it works...

I will try to find out the differences between my 2 installations.